# install Quartz as windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz server as a windows service to schedule a task. I want Quartz server to be part of Visual studio installer project. I have created a custom action for QuartzServer.exe but it is not getting installed as a Service with setup execution. How to accomplish this?

Comment: The .net version quartz-scheduler.net or the Java version?

Comment: @AlexK. its for .net version.

Comment: "I have created a custom action for QuartzServer.exe" Care to tell us what this is? It seems like it might be important.

Comment: @spender in visual studio installer project we can specify custom action to install windows services so as a part of installation it will install required windows service that we have developed.same way i created custom action for Quartz Server.exe but it is not getting installed as a service with installation.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx

Comment: @AlexK. i followed same post but it explains the manual process to install Quartz as Windows Service what I would like do is to automate Quarz service installation.

Comment: @AlexK,@spender thank you for your time to answer my question i found a lead where Quartz Server is based on topshelf  and topshelf based Windows Services use there own mechanism to install services

Answer (score 1):

Quartz Server Windows Service is based on topshelf so topshelf uses its own framework commands to install windows services.following link explains mechanism that can be used to integrate with MSI installer

http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2010/01/09/how-to-integrate-a-topshelf-based-service-with-vs-setup-projects/

Comment: This link is broken, do you know of another location with this information that you could copy into your answer?

Comment: I used this long time ago so not sure exact information where it would be available. Have you look at the following. https://medium.com/cheranga/creating-and-scheduling-a-windows-service-using-topshelf-and-quartz-in-net-core-aae68b8390c

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx